# How do i check each line of file in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to C
i'm asked to check if the format of the text file input is right or not!
the file should have lines like this :

```
1-float
2-('+'/'*'/'-')
3-flaot
4-'='
5-the result of the above operation
6-';'
```

I read the file and place each char in an array but have no idea what to do next 
here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
/*Max number of characters to be read/write from file*/
#define MAX_CHAR_FOR_FILE_OPERATION 1000000 



int main()
{

   char *filename = "D:\input.txt";
   FILE *fp;
   char text[MAX_CHAR_FOR_FILE_OPERATION];
   int i;

   fp = fopen(filename, "r");

   if(fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("File Pointer is invalid\n");
      return -1;
   }
   //Ensure array write starts from beginning
   i = 0;

   //Read over file contents until either EOF is reached or maximum characters is read and store in character array
   while( (fgets(&text[i++],sizeof(char)+1,fp) != NULL) && (i<MAX_CHAR_FOR_FILE_OPERATION) ) ;

   //Ensure array read starts from beginning


   fclose(fp);



   getche();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you parsing files fomatted like `#.### [op] #.### = #.###`?

Comment: Show an example of a valid input line.

Comment: @Mosby: I think that's what he means, but also for there to be a semicolon at the end (token 6), e.g. `1.1 + 2.2 = 3.3;`, but hard to be certain without examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not 100% clear what you want to do here.

If all you want to do is check that the expression is syntactically correct, that's one thing. If you want to check that it is *also* arithmetically correct (i.e. that the result on the RHS of the `=` is actually the result of the arithmetic expression on the LHS), that's another.

In either case, you must parse the input lines. There are several ways of doing this. The canonical, general, and *robust* way is to tokenize the lines with a *lexer* and pass the tokens from the lexer to a *parser*, which is a kind of finite state machine that “knows” the *grammar* of the language you are trying to parse (in this case infix arithmetic expressions). Given that you asked this question, it's reasonable to assume that you haven't got to this kind of material yet.

In your case, you are only dealing with simple infix arithmetic expressions of the form:

```
NUMBER OPERATOR NUMBER = NUMBER ;
```

You can get away with checking for lines that “look” exactly like this with one of the `scanf()` family of functions, but this is a *fragile* solution: if you add another term to the expression on the left, it will break; it takes considerable care to craft the correct format string; and it does *not* check for arithmetic correctness.

If all you need is something this simple, you can do it like this (I have omitted the file I/O):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define OPERATOR_CLASS "[-+/*]"


bool is_a_binary_infix_expression(const char *expr)
{
    int   count;                // Count returned by sscanf()                                                                                      
    float left_opd;             // Left operand                                                                                                    
    char  operator[2] = {'\0'}; // Operator                                                                                                        
    float right_opd;            // Right operand                                                                                                   
    float result;               // Result                                                                                                          
    char  junk;                 // Trailing junk                                                                                                   

    // Format specifier for sscanf():                                                                                                              
    const char *format = "%f %1" OPERATOR_CLASS "%f =%f ; %c";

    // Attempt conversion:                                                                                                                         
    count = sscanf(expr, format, &left_opd, operator, &right_opd, &result, &junk);

    // If exactly 4 conversions succeeded, the expression was good. If fewer,                                                                      
    // the conversion failed prematurely. If 5, there was trailing junk:                                                                           
    return count==4;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int n_lines;
    char *lines[]={
        "1.5+2.2=3.7;",
        "1.5 + 2.2 = 3.7 ; ",
        "a+2.2=3.7;",
        "1.5+2.2=3.7;x",
    };


    n_lines = (int)sizeof(lines)/sizeof(char *);

    for(i=0; i<n_lines; i++) {
        printf("'%s' is %s\n", lines[i], is_a_binary_infix_expression(lines[i]) ? "OK" : "NOT OK");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This only checks for syntactic correctness. If you want to check for arithmetic correctness, you can `switch` on the operand to compute the correct result and compare that with the result extracted from the input line, but be careful not to fall into the trap of doing a direct comparison with `==`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I can think of is to create an automata. That could be an enum with steps, for exemple:

```
enum AUTOMATE
{
    FirstFloat = 0,
    FirstSign,
    SecondFloat,
    EqualSign,
    Answer
};
```

More info on how to use enum here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t.aspx

If you already have all each char in an array, iterate over the entire array using whichever loop you want, and check the integer value of each char. Use this table http://www.asciitable.com/ to check weather the integer value represents a number or a sign (-, +, =, etc). When each step is passed, tell your automate to go further (+=1). If you reach the end, you verified it. If not, then format is wrong.

Comment: What is “an automate” and how do you create one? ;)

Comment: Sorry, I just notice "automate" is just a french word and I was too dumb to remember the english translation. But it is just a way to recognize a pattern. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming).
For your purpose, you could also just use an int and if it reaches 5, you're good. If on of the steps fails, put it back to 0 and note the string as a failed pattern.

Comment: You were thinking of a "Finite State Automaton" (which has a pl. *automata*); more conventional is "finite state machine", or "FSM" in short. SO has [a tag `fsm`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fsm).